# Xcode - Provisioning profile failed qualification

Tags: xcode

I am facing this issue for a second day now when I try to upload a tvOS build to App Store Connect I get this error saying "Profile doesn't include the com.apple.developer.associated-appclip-app-identifiers entitlement." and the weird thing is that my app doesn't even have App Clip added as a target whatsoever. Any help? Thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUVKS.png)

Comment: have u found a solution ? i still can't remove the app clip entitlements from my app , when i try to upload at final stage its keep showing me the app clip still there

Answer (score 3):

You just go to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` and delete files inside.

Then Xcode will automatically generate the new profiles and you can archive again without any problems